# How to setup nginx for multiple website under one domain?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I created two websites (with database) using django, let's call them web1 (database=web1_db) and web2 (database=web2_db). I'd like to run them under one domain in this way (main.html for example, each website has url.py to direct pages):

www.mywebsite.com/web1/main.html

www.mywebsite.com/web2/main.html

I'm using nginx and uwsgi to serve the website and I can get web1 and web2 work separately. To serve both websites as stated above, I setup uwsgi in emperor mode (successfully, I think), but I can't figure out how I should config nginx to make this work. Can someone give me some suggestion?

my nginx conf for single website is as below:

```
upstream mywebsite {
server unix:///tmp/mywebsite.sock;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name www.mywebsite.com;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

location /media{
    alias /pathtomedia;
}

location /static{
    alias /pathtostatic;
}

location / {
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    uwsgi_pass mywebsite;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use two (web1 and web2) upstreams and for each location block `location /web1 { something; }` uwsgi_pass to your upstreams.

You might also need to rewrite the urls so the actual "/web*" part of your url doesn't get passed on to the upstream. Basically, so the upstream thinks that the request is actually "/whatever" instead of "/web1/whatever".

That benig said, it entirely depends on your setup and for anyone to help with regards to any url rewriting (if even required), much more infos is needed.

You might want to check this answer [Defining correctly Nginx server block for two django apps and no server_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230886/defining-correctly-nginx-server-block-for-two-django-apps-and-no-server-name) which could potentially help you on your way.